# What happens when you don't create a package and have a protected variable?

Tags: java

I have two public classes class A and B.

```
public class A{
protected int x;

}

public class B{
A a = new A();
a.x // still possible even though its protected

}
```

In class A I define a protected variable, but I can still access this variable in B. Why, when it's protected?

I heard it is because they are in the same package, but this makes me confused. I didn't even create a package yet so how does protected work in this case? Are the two classes of the same non-existent package if I don't create packages for them to be in?

I tried outputting in both classes with

```
this.getClass().getPackage()
```

and it both gives me "null". So I don't understand what is going on here. are they in the same package or not?

Comment: Two classes in the null package are still in the same package.

Comment: So is the protected variable visible because they both are in the same unnamed package?

Comment: The JLS specifies that a JVM implementation can support more than 1 default package (why i don't know), but for your purposes here you can assume there's only one and both your classes are in the same package.